# Which plugins should I use to build an Intranet in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, intranet

We are looking to develop an intranet that will have department pages (HR, Sales, etc.), each department's landing page is going to have its own news/announcements section and downloads (PDFs and Docs). The site will also have a calendar of events and a directory of employees that needs to be searchable separately. What are the essential plugins for such an implementation to make posting of content to different sections painless? Should a CMS solution like CustomPress be used? I would appreciate your insights.

Answer (score 1):

For user controls, look at User Access Manager
For other CMS features, I would look at Pods
For the directories, you would need to set up different groups of users and then have a directory page that filters the directory by group. That sounds like a custom page rather than a plugin.
For the calendar, the My Calendar plugin is popular and actively developed.

As an aside, this project does not sound like something Wordpress excels at. Your site sounds like it would be better in Drupal/Joomla. If you already have Wordpress experience and want to build on it, then you can hack it to work like a CMS, but, at its core, it is not designed to do the types of things you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Woffice theme. It has all those features right in the box and a great documentation: https://woffice.io/